# The exponential of a straight line is a straight line if and only if the line is horizontal

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, proof-verification

Suppose that $f(z) = e^{z}$. Show that the image of a straight line $\ell$ in $\mathbb{C}$ under $f$ is a straight line if and only if $\ell$ is horizontal.
My attempt:
Suppose $\ell$ is horizontal. Then for the complex number $z=x+iy$, $y=d$ for fixed $d \in \mathbb{R}$.
Hence,
$$e^z = e^x e^{id} = e^{x}\cos d + i \sin d$$
which, geometrically, is a complex number with fixed argument $d$ radians, with a variable length $e^{x}$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence, as $x$ varies, then $e^{z}$ traces out a straight line.

Now suppose that the image of $z$ under $f$ is a straight line. Then
$$e^{z} = e^x \cos y + e^x i \sin y.$$
If the image of $z$ under $f$ is a straight line, then the argument of $e^z$ for any $z$ is fixed. This implies $y$ is fixed.

However, I'm quite confused now. Even though I fix $y=d$ in the first implication, $z=x+id$ still doesn't look horizontal to me in the Argand diagram... (**scratch this**, I realise it actually does haha)

I'm not sure if I proved the last implication correctly, it seems kind of dodgy. I say that $y$ is fixed, but do I have to say anything about $x$?

Comment: For the second part you have to assume an arbitrary straight line, i.e., $t\in\mathbb{R}\mapsto z(t) = z_0 + z_1 t$ with arbitrary $z_0,z_1\in\mathbb{C}$. How do you imply that the phase of $e^z$ is fixed? Is the imaginary part of  $t\in\mathbb{R}\mapsto \ln(t+i)$ fixed?!

Answer (score 1):

Parametrizing a line as $l(t)=(1-t)(x+iy)+t(x'+iy')$, we get $$\Im(f(l(t))=e^{(1-t)x+tx'}\sin((1-t)y+ty')$$

As $t$ ranges, the argument of $\sin$ will hit infinitely many multiples of both $\pi$ and $\pi/2$ unless $y=y'$. Which of these cases result in a straight line?

Comment: What does $x'$ and $y'$ refer to?

Comment: The line $l$ is defined as the line passing thru two complex numbers, one being $z=x+iy$ and the other being $z'=x'+iy'$

Comment: Ahh I see. Also, the case that $y=y'$ implies $\ell$ is a horizontal line, but why do we need $y=y'$ in the first place? (I'm not sure why we require $\sin$ to not hit multiples of $\pi$ and $\pi /2$.

Comment: You have proven that if the line is horizontal, it gets mapped to a straight line. The above argument shows that if the line is not horizontal, then it is not mapped to a straight line, since a straight line cannot go back and forth from having an imaginary part to not having an imaginary part

Answer (score 0):

Supose the line is not horizontal i.e. $z=x+iy$, $y$ is not fixed and $-\infty<y<\infty$, $x\in \mathbb R$.

$e^z=e^x(cos y +isin y)$ has argument $\theta =y\not\in (-π/2,π/2)$, so the image is not an oblique or vertical line. Moreover, $\theta =y\not\in (0,π)$, so the image is not a horizontal line in upper half plane.